# Is it possible to use nativescript preview functionality with HMR?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, webpack-hmr

I'm using the 'tns preview' command for debugging my app, but HMR doesn't seem to be working.
I've generated a blank vue project using the 'tns create' command and started it with the preview functionality. The application is successfully deployed to an Android device, but any code changes I make won't be applied to the device.
Is this not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: HRM still has few issues with NativeScript Vue, you may follow up on [Github](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+hmr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by adding the following option in the webpack config file:

watchOptions: {
    poll: 1000 // Check for changes every second
  }

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using `--no-hmr` option while using nativescript-vue.
Even it will watch changes, it won't show always expected behaves.

Restarting of the application just takes 3-5 seconds but saves you lots of trouble in long term.

`tns preview --no-hmr` or `tns run --no-hmr`

**--no-hmr** - Disables Hot Module Replacement (HMR). In this case, when a change in the code is applied, CLI will transfer the modified files and restart the application.